# Passing props from class to nested functional component

Tags: reactjs

I want to passing props through class to a nest function component, just like

```
import ComponentC from ...;

class ComponentA extends Component {
  ComponentB = ({propA, propB}) => (
    ...
  )
  render() {
    <ComponentC
      Component={ComponentB}
    />
  }
}

Class ComponentD extends Component {
  render() {
    <ComponentA
      propA="..."
      propB="..."
    />
  }
}
```

The ComponentD passing props (propA, propB) to ComponentA which have a nested function ComponentB with a deconstruction method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import ComponentC from ...;

class ComponentA extends Component {
  ComponentB = ({propA, propB}) => (
    ...
  )
  render() {
    <ComponentC
      Component={()=><ComponentB {...this.props}/>}
    />
  }
}

Class ComponentD extends Component {
  render() {
    <ComponentA
      propA="..."
      propB="..."
    />
  }
}
```

Notice the following part:
`()=><ComponentB {...this.props}/>`

so i am returning instance of your `ComponentB` from an arrow function and passing the props passed to `ComponentA` to `ComponentB`.

Comment: I think the ComponentB should be moved out of class to fit this solution

Comment: yes sure, i kept it within `ComponentA` only because your code had it like that. and i think nested component is surely valid and sometime its useful. so i thought may be its useful for you. if you want i can move it out of `ComponentA`.